# Converting HTML to ReactJS Components

Tags: html, reactjs, components

I'm doing this exercise to grasp a complete understanding of how to to convert HTML to component in Reactjs but it produced error. Concerned that I have misplaced some of react elements in my component. Can anyone give me a bullet point of what goes where from HTML to my react JavaScript components.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Audio File Loader</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A way to make sure files have loaded before playing them">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!--
       Some browsers' autoplay policy requires that an AudioContext be initialized
       during an input event in order to correctly synchronize.
       So provide a simple button to get things started.
  -->
  <button id="startbutton">Press to load tracks</button>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <section id="tracks">
      <ul>
        <li data-loading="true">
          <a href="leadguitar.mp3" class="track">Lead Guitar</a>
          <p class="loading-text">Loading...</p>
          <button data-playing="false" aria-decribedby="guitar-play-label" class="playbutton">
            <span id="guitar-play-label">Play</span>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li data-loading="true">
          <a href="bassguitar.mp3" class="track">Bass Guitar</a>
          <p class="loading-text">Loading...</p>
          <button data-playing="false" aria-describedby="bass-play-label" class="playbutton">
            <span id="bass-play-label">Play</span>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li data-loading="true">
          <a href="drums.mp3" class="track">Drums</a>
          <p class="loading-text">Loading...</p>
          <button data-playing="false" aria-describedby="drums-play-label" class="playbutton">
            <span id="drums-play-label">Play</span>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li data-loading="true">
          <a href="horns.mp3" class="track">Horns</a>
          <p class="loading-text">Loading...</p>
          <button data-playing="false" aria-describedby="horns-play-label" class="playbutton">
            <span id="horns-play-label">Play</span>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li data-loading="true">
          <a href="clav.mp3" class="track">Clavi</a>
          <p class="loading-text">Loading...</p>
          <button data-playing="false" aria-describedby="clavi-play-label" class="playbutton">
            <span id="clavi-play-label">Play</span>
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="sourced">All tracks sourced from <a href="http://jplayer.org/">jplayer.org</a></p>
    </section>
  </div><!-- wrapper -->

<script type="text/javascript">
console.clear();

// for cross browser compatibility
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let audioCtx = null;

// Provide a start button so demo can load tracks from an event handler for cross-browser compatibility
const startButton = document.querySelector('#startbutton');
console.log(startButton);

// select all list elements
const trackEls = document.querySelectorAll('li');
console.log(trackEls);

// switch aria attribute on click
// allPadButtons.forEach(el => {
//   el.addEventListener('click', () => {
//     if (el.getAttribute('aria-checked') === 'false') {
//       el.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'true');
//     } else {
//       el.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'false');
//     }
//   }, false)
// })


// Loading ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// function for fetching the audio file and decode the data
async function getFile(filepath) {
  const response = await fetch(filepath);
  const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
  const audioBuffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
  return audioBuffer;
}

// function to call each file and return an array of decoded files
async function loadFile(filePath) {
  const track = await getFile(filePath);
  return track;
}

let offset = 0;
// create a buffer, plop in data, connect and play -> modify graph here if required
function playTrack(audioBuffer) {
  const trackSource = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  trackSource.buffer = audioBuffer;
  trackSource.connect(audioCtx.destination)

  if (offset == 0) {
    trackSource.start();
    offset = audioCtx.currentTime;
  } else {
    trackSource.start(0, audioCtx.currentTime - offset);
  }

  return trackSource;
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audioCtx != null) {
    return;
  }

  audioCtx = new AudioContext();

  document.querySelector("#startbutton").hidden = true;

  trackEls.forEach((el, i) => {

    // get children
    const anchor = el.querySelector('a');
    const loadText = el.querySelector('p');
    const playButton = el.querySelector('.playbutton');

    // load file
    loadFile(anchor.href).then((track) => {

      // set loading to false
      el.dataset.loading = 'false';

      // hide loading text
      loadText.style.display = 'none';

      // show button
      playButton.style.display = 'inline-block';

      // allow play on click
      playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

        // check if context is in suspended state (autoplay policy)
        if (audioCtx.state === 'suspended') {
          audioCtx.resume();
        }

        playTrack(track);
        playButton.dataset.playing = true;
      })
    })
  })
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general gist is this;

You create a react component, and;

- You place everything from the  of the html inside the renders return method of your react component. Don't forget to change things like classname to className.
- You put the CSS in a .css file, and import it at the top of your jsx file with the component.
- Any javascript can be placed inside your component, before the render method. You will want to read up on hooks and states to utilize the power of react. Otherwise, all the js you put inside just naively runs on every rendering.
- The head tag includes things like title and favicons, which you want to place in the public/index.js file of your react app.

Let me know if you have any questions :-)

Comment: Thanks, got it! :) Did several reading. Still confused: 1) when to put some html part in a state; 2) which part goes into componentDid/Will

Comment: 1) Don't put HTML in a state ever. If you want to manipulate the html using a state do so using JSX. For more info, see the react doc getting started. They have exercises concerning state and the lifecyckle hooks (didMount etc).
2) Don't use components - use functional react. Then it will be a useEffect. If you do use component's, componentDid will trigger after an event and componentWill will trigger before applying an event. didMount is like an on load of that specific component.